# Checking if a value exists in two or more arrays in php

Tags: php

Hi there I have this problem here:
I have this on my controller:

```
 $questions = Question::select('text','question_image','question_type_id','id')
                                ->whereIn('id', $question_ids)
                                ->where('deleted', 0)
                                ->orderBy('created_at','ASC')
                                ->paginate(20);
```

which ouputs this:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#1635 ▼
  #total: 4
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#1627 ▼
    #items: array:4 [▼
      0 => Question {#1622 ▼
        #hidden: array:1 [▶]
        #fillable: array:10 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:4 [▼
          "text" => "asd"
          "question_image" => null
          "question_type_id" => 5
          "id" => 1213
        ]
        #original: array:4 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: []
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
      1 => Question {#1623 ▶}
      2 => Question {#1624 ▶}
      3 => Question {#1625 ▶}
```

And then I have this one:

```
$owner_questions = BankQuestion::select('question_id')->where('bank_id', $bank_id)->where('user_id',  $auth)->where('deleted', 0)->get()->toArray();
```

Which outputs this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "question_id" => 1217
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "question_id" => 1218
  ]
]
```

And here I have my **loop** of questions:

```
  foreach ($questions as $question) {

              if(in_array($question->id,  $owner_questions )){
                     $question->authorQuestion = 1;
                }else{
                    $question->authorQuestion = 0;
                }
    }
```

Here I need to find the `$question->id`  that exists on `$owner_questions` arrays  which there the numbers that I am looking for are 1217 and 1218. Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong here please..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing numeric value($question->id) with an array, which has a property question_id. Here is what you can do:

```
$owner_questions_ids = array();
foreach($owner_questions as $owner_question){
    $owner_questions_ids[] = $owner_question['question_id'];
}

// now you can compare them
in_array($question->id,  $owner_questions_ids )
```

Comment: It's worth noting this isn't very efficient (it's exponential) so don't do this with large arrays. Make an id lookup first instead.

Comment: I.e. `$owner_questions_ids[$owner_question['question_id']] = $owner_question;` instead and then simply check for `isset($owner_questions_ids[$question->id])`